# How to setup email or splunk alerts when Rabbitmq unacked messages increases

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to understand/research if we can set up alerts when messages queues is not drained or when Rabbitmq unacked messages increases

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to index the health data from RabbitMQ. There are a couple of API endpoints where RabbitMQ exposes this data at, for example /api/overview, /api/queues, api/nodes

To fetch the data to Splunk you can use the REST TA: https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1546/

Last step, after you've identified the metrics you'd like to keep an eye on and worked out conditions to alert on, you can create Alerts in Splunk.

[image]
https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html#rabbitmq-metrics